# float error while using a float - custom messages

Tags: ros2, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am receiving this error.

```
[example36-1]     self.age.year = 2022
[example36-1]   File "/home/user/ros2_ws/install/custom_interfaces/lib/python3.8/site-packages/custom_interfaces/msg/_age.py", line 131, in year
[example36-1]     assert \
[example36-1] AssertionError: The 'year' field must be of type 'float'
```

Only, I am using a float.

```
from custom_interfaces.msg import Age

...

    def on_shutdown(self):
        self.age.year = 2022
        self.age.month = 5
        self.age.day = 1
        self.get_logger().info('date this program was made : %s' %
                               self.age.day + '/%s' % self.age.month + '/%s' % self.age.year)
```

And if you'd like to see the age message type

```
float32 year
float32 month
float32 day
```

Pretty sure I compiled it correctly and stuff since when I run

```
user:~/ros2_ws$ ros2 interface show custom_interfaces/msg/Age
float32 year
float32 month
float32 day
```

It spits it out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399947/float-error-while-using-a-float---custom-messages/) by [Electrolight](https://answers.ros.org/users/103871/electrolight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Only, I am using a float.
>
> ```
> from custom_interfaces.msg import Age
>
> ...
>
>     def on_shutdown(self):
>         self.age.year = 2022
> ```

isn't `2022` an `int`?

at least Python seems to think it is:

```
>>> type(2022)
<class 'int'>
```

To make it a `float`:

```
>>> type(float(2022))
<class 'float'>
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Electrolight](https://answers.ros.org/users/103871/electrolight/) on 2022-05-03**:
Thank you for your help :) You put me on the right path. So best I can tell. Python sees "2022" and takes a guess that it's an integer. Then ros2 panics since the data type and message don't agree.

.

Storing the value as:
self.age.year = float(2022)

Or as:
self.age.year = 2022.0

Both work... but yield a result like:
[example36]: date this program was made : 1.0/5.0/2022.0

.

So it seems the easiest course of action is to update the message type to an integer and then perhaps the whole fiasco is averted.

.

Thank you!

-rosnoob